# Method for adding a Watermark Logo/Text to bottom of each Sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, css, master-page, style.css

#### I'm currently trying to add a Watermark Logo or text to the bottom of every Sharepoint site/Subsite.

Can anyone recommend an effective way to do so?

I've tried various incarnations of CSS using the Master Page's CSS file. The closest I can get is a repeating background image of my watermarked logo using:

> body.ms-backgroundImage {
> background: url(/my/image.png);
> }

I've tried various things such as no-repeat, trying to fix the position and even !important tags to try position this Watermarked image but to no avail.

Anything else I can try?

Comment: Do you have permission to edit master pages? If yes, then within s4-bodyContainer div, insert another div with position fixed to bottom of page and within it place an image. That can solve your problem.

Comment: Yes full permissions to access the master page and apply a custom CSS file.

Comment: You want to have this watermark logo as to be sticky on the bottom of the page or like you need to scroll to the bottom of the page to view this logo?

Comment: Ideally sticky, so I've also looked at using a sticky footer as one of the options but still would like to know both options just so I have some flexibility. In terms of adding the s4-bodyContainer div, currently adding that to my master page.

Comment: Do not forget that you should never modify the original masterpage files. Make a copy of Seattle or Oslo and male your changes there.

Comment: Of course. As much fun as it would be to completely break an already fragile system, I made V2's of the originals!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly use the following code in you master page. Add it just above the closing body tags.

```
<div style="position:fixed; bottom: 10px; right: 10px; width: 40px; height: 100px;" class="s4-notdlg ms-dialogHidden">
        <img src="asd.png" alt="no image text" />
    </div>
```

This will give an image on the right bottom corner of your page. Also note that I had added two classes to the wrapping div. The use of these class is to hide the image/watermark from the dialogs box. The first class name is for SP2010 while the other works for SP2013 and SP2016.

Adding the image below of my master page to give you idea where i put this in master page.

[image]

Comment: Absolutely spot on. Works a treat.

Answer (score 2):

As per you comment, you can update masterpage.

Simply add following snippet before `s4-bodyContainer`:

```
<div class="s4-notdlg ms-dialogHidden" style="
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 20px;
z-index: 1000000;
opacity: 0.7;
">
    <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" border="0">
</div>
```

This will  make watermark like sticky icon on every page as below screen.

[image]

Later on you can put this inline style to your css by specifying the class.

Also you can specify any content within that `div` to update your watermark content.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem will be, this will be visible on all the pages including OOTB dialog box. Just wrap the div with `s4-notdlg ms-dialogHidden` classes so it wont cause any issue on dialog box.

Comment: Oh yes, that's correct. Thanks for the notation. Answer updated!!

Comment: Thank you for the help as well Pradip, this code will also come in handy. Much appreciated.